# Play Framework not refreshing page when javascript posts a change

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

So issue I have is that I have 2 combo boxes, comboONE and comboTWO.
comboTWO's population is dependent on the selection of comboONE ... i.e. when comboONE is selected I want to hit the server and pass in the relevant values for comboTWO.

Everything seems to be joinning up and even the call that returns from Controller gets called .. but weirdly does not refresh the page ... this is true if I send it to an entirely different page.

So some code ... the scala template looks like ...

```
@(adminAccess: Boolean, theLocationClassTimes: List[String])
<!DOCTYPE html>

:
:
    <script>
        function populateClassTimeSelect(classLocation) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
        req.open("post", "/locationclasstimes/" + classLocation);
        req.onload = function ( e ) {
            if ( req.status = 200 )  {
                document.reload(true);
            }
        };
        req.send();
        }
    </script>
:
// And use "theLocationClassTimes" list down here
```

The routes file has ...

```
GET         /contacts.html                            controllers.Application.contacts
POST        /locationclasstimes/:classLocation        controllers.Application.locationClassTimes(classLocation: String)
```

... and then the controller is like ...

```
 def contacts = SecureAction { request =>
    Ok(views.html.contacts(isAdminUser(request), List("andyOne", "andyTwo")))
  }

  def locationClassTimes(classLocation: String) = SecureAction  { request =>
    val validClassTimesForLocation = List("Hello1","Hello2", classLocation)
    Ok(views.html.contacts(!isAdminUser(request), validClassTimesForLocation))
  }
```

What I should say is that the naming is poor here .. but basically the "locationClassTimes" function does get called as expected , and does create my new list.
But the HTML page does not refresh with the new content.
And if I send it an entirely different page I can see that it does the required processing ( i.e. reading DB for that page ) but doesn't actually render it.

So I guess I have two main questions:
(1) Is there something obvious I am doing wrong to connect the dots here 
(2) Is there an easier way to connect comboONE with comboTWO in play framework .. I do want to hit the service/DB tier at this point.

Many thanks for any pointers at all as I am entirely new to all things front end webby!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't AJAX back the`validClassTimesForLocation` list? That whole `document.reload(true)` stuff looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for that @millhouse   when i said I was new to Web apps I meant it ;-)   So I've had a wee go at the AJAX linking and works as you mention .. so I'll go down this route for sure in the meantime ... I have the new Mastering Play Framework for Scala book so perhaps there is a more idiomatic way within the framework but your suggestion is exactly what I needed to break this particular knowledge block.  Cheers!